Flutter File picker platformException
Hello i would like to ask, is there a way to resolve this platform exption while picking files from google drive

I/flutter ( 2761): Error while picking file: PlatformException(unknown_path, Failed to retrieve path., null, null)

    class _FilePickerScreenState extends State<FilePickerScreen> {
  File? _pickedFile;

  void _pickFile() async {
    try {
      FilePickerResult? result = await FilePicker.platform.pickFiles();
      if (result != null) {
        setState(() {
          _pickedFile = File(result.files.single.path!);
        });
      }
    } on PlatformException catch (e) {
      print('Error while picking file: $e');
    }
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('File Picker Demo'),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: [
            ElevatedButton(
              onPressed: _pickFile,
              child: Text('Pick File'),
            ),
            SizedBox(height: 20),
            if (_pickedFile != null)
              Text(
                'Selected File: ${_pickedFile!.path.split('/').last}',
                style: TextStyle(fontSize: 16),
              ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}


try this code
void _pickPhoto() {
showDialog(
  context: context,
  builder: (context) {
    return AlertDialog(
      shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(18),
      ),
      title: const Text(
        "Select Picture",
        style: TextStyle(
          color: ColorsHelper.colorBlack,
        ),
      ),
      content: Column(
        mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
        children: [
          OutlinedButton(
            style: const ButtonStyle(
                backgroundColor:
                    MaterialStatePropertyAll(ColorsHelper.colorPrimary)),
            child: const Text(
              ' Pick from Camera ',
              style: TextStyle(color: ColorsHelper.colorWhite),
            ),
            onPressed: () async {
              Navigator.pop(context);
              selectimage(
                ImageSource.camera,
              );
            },
          ),
          OutlinedButton(
            style: const ButtonStyle(
                backgroundColor:
                    MaterialStatePropertyAll(ColorsHelper.colorPrimary)),
            child: const Text(
              'Select from Gallery',
              style: TextStyle(color: ColorsHelper.colorWhite),
            ),
            onPressed: () async {
              Navigator.pop(context);
              selectimage(
                ImageSource.gallery,
              );
            },
          ),
          const SizedBox(
            height: 2,
            ),
          ],
        ),
      );
    },
  );
}



 void selectimage(ImageSource source) async {
 XFile? pickedFile = await ImagePicker().pickImage(
  source: source,
 );
 if (pickedFile != null) {
  _imagefile = File(pickedFile.path);
  _cropImage(
    _imagefile!.path,
    );
  }
}


  Future<void> _cropImage(String path) async {
  CroppedFile? croppedFile = await ImageCropper().cropImage(
  sourcePath: path,
  aspectRatioPresets: Platform.isAndroid
      ? [
          CropAspectRatioPreset.square,
          CropAspectRatioPreset.ratio3x2,
          CropAspectRatioPreset.original,
          CropAspectRatioPreset.ratio4x3,
          CropAspectRatioPreset.ratio16x9
        ]
      : [
          CropAspectRatioPreset.original,
          CropAspectRatioPreset.square,
          CropAspectRatioPreset.ratio3x2,
          CropAspectRatioPreset.ratio4x3,
          CropAspectRatioPreset.ratio5x3,
          CropAspectRatioPreset.ratio5x4,
          CropAspectRatioPreset.ratio7x5,
          CropAspectRatioPreset.ratio16x9
        ],
  uiSettings: [
    AndroidUiSettings(
      activeControlsWidgetColor: ColorsHelper.colorPrimary,
      toolbarTitle: 'Crop Image',
      toolbarColor: ColorsHelper.colorBlack,
      toolbarWidgetColor: ColorsHelper.colorWhite,
      initAspectRatio: CropAspectRatioPreset.original,
      lockAspectRatio: false,
    ),
    IOSUiSettings(
      title: 'Crop Image',
    ),
  ],
);
if (croppedFile != null) {
  setState(() {
    _imagefile = File(croppedFile.path);
    });
  }
}

added on AndroidMenifest file
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="your.package.name">

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
<uses-permission 
android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" 
 />

  <application
    ...
  </application>
  </manifest>

